# Android background service for Smack (XMPP) chat application

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I am implementing a chat app using asmack library. I want to start a always running service where all the connection management task is to be done and that should be keep on receiving the incoming packets and saving the messages in my sqlite database. And as my app is launched I want my app to be notified too for the incoming messages while the background service is inserting the messages into sqlite database.
How to implements such structure with sticky service. Is partial wake lock also needed. Since, images are also to be downloaded using http partially sometimes on specific demand.

Comment: Perhaps you can get an idea from this about the way of using a background service with a listener: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14478281/5361779

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can start the service after registration on the server.

onStartCommand of service login the user.

Implement service with PacketListener,ConnectionListener,InvitationListener

**PacketListener** for Receiving Groupcaht or One to One chat messages.

**ConnectionListener** to check if connection to the server is connected or disconnected.

**InvitationListener** For getting Group invitations.

After successful login add these listeners.

Now when the message is received save that message in local database and send a Broadcast for the activities who want the message to be received.

Check if the app is in the background if yes then send the notification for the new message

Mail me if any buddy face any issue cvofjaspreet@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also want the app to keep on receiving messages while being in background. But for this the user must be online But as the user leaves the chat window the user gets offline in my app.

Comment: Then your connection must be breaking 

Implement ConnectionListener to check where connection is closing.

1 up please for the answer

Comment: Actually, I want to start a "started service(unbind)" whose task is to handle everything from receiving messages to sending messages. I want my client is to be just like a interface that will issue the commands to service And the service will do the necessary.

Comment: For that there are listeners in the started service But how to send commands from app to service to do other work like sending message.

Comment: you can see this example http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.in/2012/05/bind-service-using-ibinder-class.html

Other way of doing is send a broadcast to service

Comment: I am loading all the necessary data like rosters, vcard info, chat messages upto a certain date from sqlite to Manager classes(which provide data to UI). And I am worried about heap size. Is that ok!

Comment: Yes load the data on UI using lazy loading i.e load more data on scroll. It will work smoothly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52107/discussion-between-user2155922-and-jaspreet-singh)

Comment: @JaspreetSingh Have you maybe any Smack 4.1 demo project?

Comment: @Jaspreet/Rahul - do you have any links / sample code for the above mentioned service